# try catch bad programming practice

Tags: c#, try-catch

I am executing a stored procedure and returning a string. The string is set to return `1`,`0` or `"USER DOES NOT EXISTS"` depending on the conditions.

Just wanted to know if the following is a bad programming practice.

```
string result = _db.GetParameterValue(cmdObj, "@strMessage").ToString();
try
{
    int a = int.Parse(result);
    if (a == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("B");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

It is always better to specifically match rather than presume it was "USER NOT EXISTS" based on catching a failed int parse.

It is always bad practice to try/catch/swallow.  If you're going to catch an exception, log it or throw.

You've not specified a language, so presuming it's C#, `int.TryParse()` is much cleaner than `int.Parse` inside a `try/catch`.

Comment: thanks robrich. thats the second thought i was thinking about.

Answer (score 4):

you should use `tryParse` and **not** to include it in try catch block.

```
 int outValue = -1;
 int.TryParse(result, out outValue);
```